# How and where to write if statement to check for length()

Tags: jquery, html

Below I have a piece of code where it displays checkboxes for the selected answer buttons and counts the number of answer buttons selected.

```
function updateAnswer(context, iQuestionIndex, bDisableAppend) {
    var _sCurrQ_Class = 'q_' + iQuestionIndex;
    var _oCurrAnswerContainer = jQuery('#answer_selections .' + _sCurrQ_Class);
    if (!_oCurrAnswerContainer.length) {
        _oCurrAnswerContainer = jQuery(document.createElement('div')).addClass(_sCurrQ_Class);
        !bDisableAppend && jQuery('#answer_selections').append(_oCurrAnswerContainer);
    }

    _oCurrAnswerContainer.html('');

    var value, id;
    // loop through all buttons with 'on' status and their info to the current answer container
    $('.answerBtnsOn', context).each(function(i, btn) {

        var $btn = $(btn);
        value = btn.value;
        id = $btn.attr('id');

        var n = $("input[name='value[" + id + "]']").length;
        var hid = "hidden" + id + n + "value";    
        $(btn).attr("data-hid", hid);


        if (!bDisableAppend) {
            // append those values to the form
            var input = '<input type="checkbox" id="' + hid + '" name="value[' + iQuestionIndex + '][]" value="' + value + '" checked /><label for="' + hid + '">' + value + '</label>';
            _oCurrAnswerContainer.append(input);
        }
    });        
}
```

But I have a little issue with the counting of the number of answer buttons. I only want to count the number of answer buttons if the option type chosen is anything except for "True or False" or "Yes or No". My question is where and how do i write the appropriate if statement for this?

I have a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7sARw/25/

There is a lot of code but I have tried to cut down on the code as much as I can.

To use fiddle:

1: Open fiddle and click on the "Open Grid" in the app and select option "3". Then click on "Add Question" button.

2: You will see that a table row has been appended. In the appended table row click on any of the letter buttons, you will see that for every letter button you turn on, in the textbox above it counts how many buttons are turned on.

3: In the appended row click on the "Open Grid" link and select option "True or False". Now for this option the number of Answers textbo should always be 1, no matter how many answer buttons are on or off, it should always be 1. But problem is that if you turn on "True" or "False" button and turn it back off, it goes back to 0 as no answer button is turned on. I do not want this to happen is option is "True or False" or "Yes or No", the textbox for them two options should always be `1`.

Comment: Your question is bit hard to understand please provide Fiddle snippet, and precise of what exactly you want..

Comment: Ok give us 5 mins to provide fiddle

Comment: @ameyarote Here is the fiddle. Really what I am trying to say is that if option chosen is not "True or False" or "Yes or No", then count number of answer buttons selected, if it is "True or False" or "Yes or No", then don't perform a count of number of answers selected, keep the text input as 1 at all times

Comment: You mean to say that Changing to "True or False" in appended row ,whether it is true or false ,the answer should always be 1. isn't it?
Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @ameyarote yeah what I mean is that when you set up an answer for a "True or False" option, the answer is either "True" or "False", it can't be both and it can't be neither. So the reason I want it to always display `1` in the text box (even if no answer is selected) for this option is so the user knows that they must select one answer of either "True" or "False". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please go to following link http://jsfiddle.net/7sARw/26/

Explanation of what I have done :- Whenever  user clicks true or false to row element the answer remains "1" only.

Changes made :- go to updateAnswer function 
and see

```
 if (btn.id == "answerTrueRow" || btn.id == "answerFalseRow")
return;
```

it does not allow btn function to make any changes to answer. 
Enjoy..